# DIV - 100% height causing scroll bars

Tags: css, html

I am having a bit of issue with a div causing scroll bars when height set to 100%.

Right now, my page content looks like;

```
<body>  

<hr>

<div id="content">

    <div id="heading">

    </div>

</div>


</body>
```

The problem is that the HR is 5px, and the Content is 100% of body height. So, since it is 100% of page height, it is going below the HR and creating 5px so that a scrollbar is being made which I want to avoid..

My question is, how do I make it height 100% without it thinking that it needs to be 100%pageheight and not including the HR in the page height?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the hr inside the content div?

Comment: Won't it just fill up as you add content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of layout is best accomplished using absolute positioning. Here's an example, using your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/7KGmZ/

css:

```
#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}​
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. Also, removing the "Height" tag from the content div it still grew to the body tag.. Neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

This will however overlap over the HR.  If you set the top position to `5px`, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

- You could remove the `hr` and put a border on the `heading` `div`.
- You could remove the `hr` and put a border on the `content` `div` and change the [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property to `border-box`.
- You could move the `hr` inside the `content` `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You could set  `position: absolute`, then position it using `top: 5px` and `bottom: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in some of the elements on the top of the page having top margin, top padding or top border, my body had top border 10px, after making it 0px the slidebar disappeared.